# zip error: Invalid command arguments (cannot write zip file to terminal)

Tags: python, python-3.x, время, ос, subprocess

Изучаю книгу "Укус Питона". Там есть задача сделать программу которая будет делать копии файлов в zip архив. В книге автор реализовал эту программу с помощью библиотеки os, я же решил с помощью библиотеки subprocess, но выходит ошибка:

```
zip warning: name not matched: "/Documents/python lessons/Pi"
    zip warning: name not matched: "/Documents/python lessons/Pi 2"

zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -r "/Documents/python 

lessons/Pi 3"/20200726101518.zip . -i "/Documents/python 

lessons/Pi" "/Documents/python lessons/Pi 2")
```

Вот код:

```
import subprocess, time, os

source = ['"/Documents/python lessons/Pi"','"/Documents/python lessons/Pi 2"']
target_dir = '"/Documents/python lessons/Pi 3"'
target = target_dir + os.sep +    time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')+'.zip'
zip_command = ['zip','-r',target]

for s in source:
    zip_command.append(s)
subprocess.call(zip_command)
```

Comment: А с помощью `os` ошибки нет?

Comment: есть, та самая, что и сейчас

Comment: Ну так значит проблема в пути, используйте модуль `pathlib`

Comment: Вставил полный путь, но тоже самое(

Comment: Путь без пробелов попробуйте

Comment: zip warning: name not matched: "/home/badrabbit404/Documents/pythonlessons/name1"
 zip warning: name not matched: "/home/badrabbit404/Documents/pythonlessons/name2"

zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -r "/home/badrabbit404/Documents/pythonlessons/name3"/20200726200453.zip . -i "/home/badrabbit404/Documents/pythonlessons/name1" "/home/badrabbit404/Documents/pythonlessons/name2")

Comment: опять тоже самое выходит, может дело в системе?

Comment: Напечатайте `zip_command` прямо перед `subprocess.call`

Comment: Простите, я не очень понял вас

Comment: Сделайте `print(zip_command)`, чтобы понять, что на самом деле выполняется с помощью `subprocess.call`. Так вы узнаёте исполняемую команду, потом попробуете ввести её просто в терминал. Тем самым узнаете, проблема с кодом или нет

Comment: ['zip', '-r', '"/home/badrabbit404/Documents/pythonlessons/name3"/20200726202552.zip']

Comment: Ну вот и проблема - лишние кавычки

Comment: Спасибо, большое) Благодарю, что вытерпели всю мою тупость и помогали до конца!)